# How to add rows to a data frame based on matching IDs from a list?

Tags: r

I have a named list of dates with station ID's, month and year attached as the names. I also have another data frame with ID and state as columns. I want to add to this data frame the ranges of dates from each station, based on IDs. How would I achieve this?

**Example date list:**

```
A1_apr_23 <- structure(c(1680346800, 1680406800, 1680466800, 1680526800, 1680586800, 
                         1680646800, 1680706800, 1680766800, 1680826800, 1680886800, 1680946800, 
                         1681006800, 1681066800, 1681169160, 1681229160, 1681289160, 1681349160, 
                         1681409160, 1681469160, 1681529160, 1681589160, 1681649160, 1681709160, 
                         1681769160, 1681829160, 1681889160, 1681949160, 1682009160, 1682069160, 
                         1682129160, 1682189160, 1682249160, 1682309160), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                    "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago")

A1_dec_22 <- structure(c(1669877940, 1669937940, 1669997940, 1670057940, 1670117940, 
                         1670177940, 1670237940, 1670297940, 1670357940, 1670417940, 1670477940, 
                         1670537940, 1670597940, 1670657940, 1670717940, 1670777940, 1670837940, 
                         1670897940, 1670957940, 1671017940, 1671077940, 1671137940, 1671197940, 
                         1671257940, 1671317940, 1671377940, 1671437940, 1671497940, 1671557940, 
                         1671617940, 1671677940, 1671737940, 1671797940), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                    "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago")


B1_mar_23 <- structure(c(1677650400, 1677710400, 1677770400, 1677830400, 1677890400, 
                         1677950400, 1678010400, 1678070400, 1678130400, 1678190400, 1678250400, 
                         1678352040, 1678412040, 1678472040, 1678532040, 1678592040, 1678652040, 
                         1678712040, 1678772040, 1678832040, 1678892040, 1678952040, 1679012040, 
                         1679072040, 1679132040, 1679192040, 1679252040, 1679312040, 1679372040, 
                         1679432040, 1679492040, 1679552040, 1679612040), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                    "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago")
B1_may_23 <- structure(c(1683099260, 1683159980, 1683019980, 1683079980, 1683139980, 
                         1683199980, 1683259980, 1683319980, 1683379980, 1683439980, 1683499980, 
                         1683559980, 1683619980, 1683679980, 1683781980, 1683841980, 1683901980, 
                         1683961980, 1684021980, 1684081980, 1684141980, 1684201980, 1684261980, 
                         1684321980, 1684381980, 1684441980, 1684543440, 1684603440, 1684663440, 
                         1684723440, 1684783440, 1684843440, 1684903440), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                    "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago") 
B1_dec_22 <- structure(c(1670520840, 1670580840, 1670640840, 1670700840, 1670760840, 
                         1670820840, 1670880840, 1670940840, 1671000840, 1671060840, 1671120840, 
                         1671180840, 1671240840, 1671300840, 1671360840, 1671420840, 1671480840, 
                         1671540840, 1671600840, 1671660840, 1671720840, 1671780900, 1671840900, 
                         1671900900, 1671960900, 1672020900, 1672080900, 1672140900, 1672200900, 
                         1672260900, 1672320900, 1672380900, 1672440900), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                    "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago")
C1_feb_23 <- structure(c(1675242060, 1675302060, 1675362060, 1675422060, 1675482060, 
                         1675542060, 1675602060, 1675662060, 1675763640, 1675823640, 1675883640, 
                         1675943640, 1676003640, 1676063640, 1676123640, 1676183640, 1676243640, 
                         1676346120, 1676406120, 1676466120, 1676526120, 1676586120, 1676646120, 
                         1676706120, 1676766120, 1676826120, 1676886120, 1676946120, 1677048600, 
                         1677108600, 1677168600, 1677228600, 1677288600), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                    "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago")

date_list <- list(A1_apr_22, A1_dec_22, B1_mar_23, B1_may_23, B1_dec_22, C1_feb_23) %>% 
  setNames(c("A1_apr_22", "A1_dec_22", "B1_mar_22", "B1_may_23", "B1_dec_22", "C1_feb_23"))
```

**example df:**

```
df <- data.frame(
  station_id = c("A1", "B1", "C1"),
  state = c("CA", "IL", "CA")
)

> df
  station_id state
1         A1    CA
2         B1    IL
3         C1    CA
```

I was able to extract the date ranges from the list.

```
date_range <- Map(
  function(d) return(lubridate::date(range(d))),
  date_list
)
```

And I would like my new data frame to look something like this:

```
new_df <- data.frame(
  station_id = c("A1", "A1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "C1"), # how do I get this part?
  state = c("CA", "CA", "IL", "IL", "IL", "CA"),
  start_date = date_range %>% sapply(`[[`, 1) %>% as.vector() %>% as.Date(origin="1970-01-01"),
  end_date = date_range %>% sapply(`[[`, 2) %>% as.vector() %>% as.Date(origin="1970-01-01")
)

> new_df
  station_id state start_date   end_date
1         A1    CA 2023-04-01 2023-04-23
2         A1    CA 2022-12-01 2022-12-23
3         B1    IL 2023-03-01 2023-03-23
4         B1    IL 2023-05-02 2023-05-23
5         B1    IL 2022-12-08 2022-12-30
6         C1    CA 2023-02-01 2023-02-24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code, the output in the last 4 rows differs from what you showed. Please check what the output you posted is correct.

```r
df1 <- date_list %>% as.data.frame() %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  mutate(station_id = str_extract(name,'\\w{1}\\d{1}')) %>% arrange(station_id)


df2 <- data.frame(
  station_id = c("A1", "B1", "C1"),
  state = c("CA", "CA", "IL")
)

df3 <- df1 %>% left_join(df2,by='station_id') %>% arrange(name,value) %>% 
  group_by(station_id,state,name) %>% slice(c(1,n())) %>% 
mutate(row=ifelse(row_number()==1,'start','end'),
value=lubridate::as_date(value)) %>% ungroup() %>% 
pivot_wider(id_cols = c(station_id,state,name),values_from = value, names_from = row) %>% 
select(-name)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  station_id state start      end       
  <chr>      <chr> <date>     <date>    
1 A1         CA    2023-04-01 2023-04-23
2 A1         CA    2022-12-01 2022-12-23
3 B1         CA    2022-12-08 2022-12-30
4 B1         CA    2023-03-01 2023-03-23
5 B1         CA    2023-05-02 2023-05-23
6 C1         IL    2023-02-01 2023-02-24
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch! my example df was wrong. I modified the question and tested your code and it works perfect. Thanks again

Comment: Actually for some reason, in `df3`, some end dates are off by 1 day. A1's end date for April 2023 should be "2023-04-23", B1's end date for May 2023 should be "2023-05-23" and C1's end date for Feb 2023 should be "2023-02-24." Why might this be happening?

Comment: got it, the issue is with the use of `as.Date`, i replaced it with `lubridate::as_date`. I updated the answer now, please check

Comment: The data in the example is still wrong, I'd suggest learning about the reprex package

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most elegant way, but you can do this with a loop.

First, create a new dataframe of one column. I used `substr` to extract the first two characters from the list names:

```
new_df <- data.frame(station_id = substr(names(date_list),1,2))
```

Then add the other columns using a `for` loop:

EDIT:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(new_df)){
  new_df$state[i] = df$state[df$station_id==new_df$station_id[i]]
}
```

And use `melt` from the reshape2 package like this:

```
library(rehape2)
new_df$start_date = melt(lapply(date_list,min))[,1]
new_df$end_date = melt(lapply(date_list,max))[,1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I tried running your code and the start and end dates i get were numbers, not dates. I did `str(new_df)` to see what was going on, and it seems like `state`, `start_date` and `end_date` are `list`?

Comment: @nightstand Yes, seems the POSIX format gets lost. I edited my post.